# How can I avoid naming my View Component cshtmls "Default.cshtml" in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, view-components

It seems that in ASP.NET Core MVC, if I want to use a View Component, I have to put them in `Views\Shared\Components\[ViewComponentName]`, and then name the file "Default.cshtml".

This is rather frustrating, as in the beginning of a large project I am helping to port from Perl CGI, I'm creating a good number of View Components and having five tabs in Visual Studio all named `Default.cshtml` is confusing.

Is there any way I can avoid this naming convention? Maybe even take them out of their folders so that the file will look like…?

```
Views\Shared\Components\[ViewComponentName].cshtml
```

I don't know if there are just some settings I can tweak or what. For the most part, I'm very new to ASP.NET, and still figuring things out. Using ASP.NET Framework instead of ASP.NET Core *is* an option, though I'd prefer not to, as a lot of the boilerplate is already done.

[The documentation on ViewComponents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) says this:

> We recommend you name the view file Default.cshtml and use the Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name} path.

Which makes me think that there is a way around this restriction, but it doesn't specify how that would work or what it would look like.

Comment: "The default view name for a view component is Default, which means your view file will typically be named Default.cshtml. You can specify a different view name when creating the view component result or when calling the View method."

Comment: @DavidG Ah, I see now. And I guess the point for them each being in their own folder is that ViewComponents can have more than one View. That seems like a bad idea to me and against the main point of having ViewComponents, but I suppose I get it.

Comment: In practice, it's fairly uncommon to have more than one view for a view component, but there's some valid use cases. For example, let's say I wanted to create a view component that could work with either Bootstrap 3 or 4. I *could* use a bunch of conditionals and branching in a single view, but it would probably make more sense to have separate views for each. Then, I could return one or the other depending on some sort of config value or parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Nic I agree that having several to dozens of files named default.cshtml is annoying. More so is having several to dozens of folders with just a single file in each folder

```
Components/ViewComponentName/default.cshtml  
Components/AnotherViewComponentName/default.cshtml  
Components/AThirdViewComponentName/default.cshtml  

et cetera
```

I understand the reasons for the recommended name and location...but I simply disagree and will accept the consequences. For those who share my cavalier attitude, View() allows you to specify a View name

```
return View("Schools", items);
```

or even to specify a path to the View if you put it in a non-standard location

```
return View("/Pages/Components/Schools.cshtml", items);
```

I'm using Razor Pages but I'm sure this works for Views/Shared/Components as well.